# rake aborted error when migrating database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans-6.9

rake aborted!
The driver encountered an error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'dbapp_development'

what should be done?

i've created the database using `rake db:create`

Comment: interesting. i've deleted my answer since i have no idea what's your issue after finding out that you've created the db through `rake db:create`.  what rake job we're you trying to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you created the db by doing `rake db:create`, the creation of database has failed silently.

In this case you need to create the database manually just like I did going into mysqlyog or mysql workbench or as what you got. This is the known bug and is discussed in knowledge base.